# Sinch - Instant Message - Push Notification received while app is closed

Tags: ios, background, push-notification, sinch, instant-message

I have the following scenario:

1. iPhoneA & iPhoneB: sinch client initialized with message support and Push Support enabled
2. iPhoneA's app is closed
3. iPhoneB sends a message to iPhoneA.
4. iPhoneA receives a notification correctly (the banner appears). So iPhoneA **open app by icon**.

How can I detect and catch received notification?

Thanks

Comment: are you using sinchClient or sinchService?

Answer (score 1):

It's all covered in the Apple docs, under `Handling Local and Remote Notifications`

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html

There's also some stuff in the Sinch docs on how to pass the objects you get into Sinch:

https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/ios-instant-messaging-using-sinchservice/#4.%20push%20with%20sinchservice

Comment: In Handling Local and Remote Notifications the Apple say: The user taps (or clicks) the app icon: If the app icon is tapped on a device running iOS, the app calls the same method (applicationDidFinishLaunching:), but furnishes no information about the notification.

Comment: The Sinch not say nothing about this scenario.